# Neural network fails to capture 2D shape possibly due to biases

Tags: java, gradient-descent

I am attempting to develop a Neural Network that I can generalize to several different applications.  As part of this, I am attempting to verify that my Neural Network works properly on a simple scenario: recognizing areas of a two-dimensional graph.

I started with the simplest case of a single line, classifying answers as above or below.  After training, the network fit the line to my satisfaction as shown in the first image. For this and the following examples the neural network was trained on 10000 points randomly sampled from around the graph. The net takes in two inputs for the x and y coordinates of each point, passes them through an 8 node hidden layer, and produces a single output (1 if above the shape, -1 if below).  My graph classifies four different areas: blue and green are CORRECTLY identified, while orange and red are INCORRECTLY identified by the neural net.  Red and green colors are used above the supplied curve whereas orange and blue are used below the supplied curve.

[image: Line]

Similarly, the network functioned properly for a line with corner, i.e. two line segments joined together at a point.

[image: Two line segments making corner]

However, it has mixed results when running on y = x^2.  Near the origin, the neural network appears to be matching the curve of the parabola reasonably well.

[image: Parabola with vertex near origin zoomed in]

Away from the origin, however, it seems to be using a single line to approximate the parabola's shape.

[image: Parabola with vertex near origin zoomed out]

Moreover, when the parabola is translated away from the origin, as in y = (x-10)^2 + 30 the neural network completely fails to capture the shape.

[image: Parabola translated away from origin]

Finally, I also tested the network approximating a circle (recognizing that one layer is not necessarily sufficient to do this) and achieved the following result. I don't know if this is typical of one hidden layer neural networks, but I thought it might provide insight into a potential problem that my net might have.

[image: Circle Test on Neural Net]

Based on these results, my current suspicion is that the biases on the net's nodes are not getting as large as they should in training, thus causing all of the line segments that the net uses to pass close to the origin, and thereby causing it to fail on approximating shapes that would require larger biases.

Any help you can provide would be much appreciated!  Feel free to let me know if sharing any sections of my code or the results of any other tests would be useful in debugging this. Thank you.

Comment: I think training on the line only and testing on the circle will not work - but gets as good as it can - you need to train on curved spaces as well